# Is my use of Early Stopping appropriate in my model selection process?

Tags: neural-networks, python, svm

My data is split into 80% train, 10% validation and 10% test. My dataset has three versions: i) Base dataset, ii) SMOTE adjusted version 1 and iii) SMOTE Adjusted version 2. I have run a 4 different model architectures against each of these datasets so effectively I have 12 models.

I ran a GridSearchCV on all the models to select the best parameters for each one and have selected the best ones, below, in green. I would now like to take the top 2 from each architecture (the ones in green) to a validation set and would like to implement early stopping here. My plan is, to take the best performing model from the validation test set from each architecture to the final test set of data. So effectively, four models would go head to head in the final test set to see which performs best.

[image]

My questions are two fold. First, does this logic make sense? Secondly, when I implement early stopping using patience of epochs = 10 as an example, would I then take the epoch it stopped at, as the one to use in training the final model in each architecture?

I understand the logic behind early stopping, in order to aid in over fitting, but I am just a bit confused in how to implement in practice. Any help would be appreciated.